# $\Delta x$ in the limit-definition, or Riemann-Sum-definition, of an Integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Every time I evaluate an integral as a Riemann Sum and I see $\Delta x$ as $\left(1/n\right)$, I think of an upper limit that could be $a+1$ and a lower limit that could be $a$, where $a$ is any real number.

Taking these values, $\Delta x$ would still be $\left(1/n\right)$, right? However, everyone else immediately evaluate the integral from $0$ to $1$. Is it not simply the integral evaluated between two numbers, and the absolute value of the difference of these two numbers is $1$?

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I would appreciate an explanation or a book that clarifies this. Thanks.

Comment: You're correct that $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$ doesn't tell you what interval you are integrating over, just its length. However, the values of the function within the sum tell you just that. If they are of the form $f(a + k/n)$ where $k$ is your summation variable, then the interval is from $a$ to $a+1$. The most common case, here, is having summands of the form $f(k/n)$, which leads to the interval of integration being from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: I understand the topic of your question, but I do not understand what point you are trying to make. What is it about an integral evaluated from 0 to 1 compared to any other interval, say 2 to 3, that you seem to be unsure of?

Comment: Thanks @Tom . You’re right, of course. I simply forgot how X(sub i), or (sub k), is defined. And ignored the fact that, in this case as you mentioned, f(i/n)=f(0+i/n) and therefore the interval is from 0 to 1, remembering that (Delta)x=(1/n). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @PhilH I understand now. As I responded to Tom, I forgot that the interval is both given by (Delta)x, which I initially considered, but also by the form of the summands, which I forgot to consider.